# When to call ListCell's getItem in Initialisation without Exceptions

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

regards to the title of the question; suppose i have a custom dataobject

```
public class Features {
 BooleanProperty message = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
 String name= "Java fx";
 //etc etc
 }
```

now when i create my `ListCell`, and do some work in my Custom Cell's class Constructor which points to lets say the `message` variable, or any variable in my dataClass, i get a `NullPointerException`, why, because the `ListCell`'s `this.getItem();` is `null`. like this

```
//im in my constructor
BooleanProperty somechangingboolean= new SimpleBooleanProperty(getItem().message);
//that above line results in NPE.
```

so how do you go about that? because i am trying to listen to changes that occur in my `message` variable of `BooleanProperty` and i want to do it in the ListCell, but my constructor evaluates/computes before the data is set, probably called in `updateItem(T item, boolean empty)` or maybe `StarEdit()`.. and i don't want to call the codes there, also  i do not want to add && remove listeners, assign && nullify stuff like a habbit ..

Any way here to get rid of the `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosh!!, i just found the solution, so i might just go ahead and post it, right? Right.. The answer was to add a listener on my `itemProperty()` and  post the rest of the constructor code there,was pretty simple, something like this -(stackoverflow requirements)

```
//in my constructor
this.itemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Features>() {

  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Features> observable,
                 Features oldValue, Features newValue) {
    System.out.println("newvalue set");
    if(newValue != null)                
        somechangingboolean.bind(getItem().message);
        // now im ok, and the rest comes in
    }
});
```

Guess its the right way..